# Passing model with dynamic json object to MVC controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I have a model like so in javascript:

```
function SomeModel()
{
   this.Id = ko.observable();
   this.Name = ko.observable();
   this.MetaData = {};
}
```

Then I need to send this to MVC so I can persist it in mongodb, however I dont know how is best to store the MetaData in the C# representation... as the model looks like:

```
public class SomeModel
{
   public Guid Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public object MetaData {get;set;}
}
```

However it doesnt like binding the json object to the object, I am not sure if I should be using an ExpandoObject or something, as I am not really that fussed about accessing the data within the c# mvc service, it is only for plugins in the front end which can store their own data on an object for use later. So an example could be:

```
var someModel = new SomeModel();
someModel.MetaData.Bookmarks = [];
someModel.MetaData.Bookmarks.push({ location: 120, document: 23003032 });
```

So it could contain anything and sub objects, and like I say I just need to bung it into an object just as a transport mechanism for Mongo, which will save it fine as its schema-less.

Currently the models from JS are sent over ajax via Jquery, and auto binded in the controller then sent off to the repository.

== Edit ==

I have done a few minor tests with MVC4, and I can put an expando object within my models and have it populated, however it only seems to store 1 layer of data, so if I were to postback:

```
...,
MetaData: {
   something: {
       one: 1,
       two: 2 
   }
},
...
```

I would end up with my expando object for the MetaData field knowing about the `something` field, but would not store any of the data below that first traversal, so is there any way to store the above other than turning it into a string of json to be stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there seemed to be no solid answers I just had to do an extra step in the jquery ajax to convert all "metadata" fields into a json string, then store it as a string on the server.

Then if I need to access or change the data I use the web helper `Json.Encode/Decode` which returns a dynamic, then I can just add child elements which I do as:

- Anonymous type for simple included json object
- List for an array element

Then I just encode it again casting the dynamic as an object.